# Statistics library for Jruby

Tags: java, ruby, r, statistics, jruby

I am looking for a statistics library in Jruby. In particular, I want to run chi-squared and Fisher tests.

Comment: Consider tagging with "ruby" and "java", as jruby will let you run either.

Comment: You may want to see if ruby-toolbox mentions any statistics gems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SuanShu has both:

- [Chi Squared Distribution](http://www.numericalmethod.com/javadoc/suanshu/com/numericalmethod/suanshu/stats/distribution/univariate/ChiSquareDistribution.html)
- [Fisher](http://www.numericalmethod.com/javadoc/suanshu/com/numericalmethod/suanshu/stats/distribution/univariate/ChiSquareDistribution.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could look at the Colt Java library and use that from JRuby. The couple of times I needed it using Java from JRuby was always quite painless.

http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it could run with JRuby, but the RinRuby gem allows to interact with an R session from a ruby script :

https://sites.google.com/a/ddahl.org/rinruby-users/Home